# Disable drawing if polygon already exists

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

With set `map.data.setControls(null)` I still can draw another polygon. How to draw only one polygon?

http://jsfiddle.net/atrxw00x/1

```
function savePolygon() {
  map.data.toGeoJson(function (json) {
    localStorage.setItem('geoData', JSON.stringify(json));
    if(json.features.length > 0) {
      map.data.setControls(null);
    } else {
      map.data.setControls(['Polygon']);
    }
    initControls(json);
  });
}
```

Comment: Going by your fiddle, you can check if there are any elements in 'polylist' dropdown and if there is then you can call: map.data.setControls(null);.
That call removes the drawing toolbars.

Comment: @BharatGupta Thanks. `map.data.setControls(null)` we still can draw a new polygon. I want to disable it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `setDrawingMode` call:

```
if (json.features.length) {
  map.data.setControls(null);
  map.data.setDrawingMode(null);
}
```

Comment: @MrJoe... You changed the question. Haha... :)